# How to print different arrays in a single line in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, multidimensional-array

I wanted to print all my array[i] in a single line in a new function, but everything gone misaligned in the table of my output.
I can't find where the problem is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void userInput();
void formOutput(int, char (*)[50], char (*)[10], int *);

void main()
{
   userInput();
}

void userInput()
{   int totalSubj;

    printf("\nHow many subject to be registered: ");
    scanf("%d",&totalSubj);

    char subjCode[totalSubj][10], subjName[totalSubj][50];
    int subjCred[totalSubj];

    for(int i=0;i<totalSubj;i++)
    {
        printf("\nSUBJECT CODE %d.: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",&subjCode[i]);

        printf("SUBJECT NAME: ");
        fgets(subjName[i],50,stdin);

        printf("SUBJECT CREDIT: ");
        scanf("%d",&subjCred[i]);
    }

    formOutput(totalSubj, subjName, subjCode, subjCred);
}

void formOutput(int subjTotal, char nameSub[][50], char codeSub[][10], int credSub[])
{
    printf("Subject Name                  Subject Code          Credit\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------------");

    for(int i=0;i<subjTotal;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s  ",nameSub[i]);
        printf("%s\t\t",codeSub[i]);
        printf("%d",credSub[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the output.
The values in the table are all messed up, some are also duplicated which is not what I wanted it to be:

```
How many subject to be registered: 3

SUBJECT CODE 1.: DCS1053
SUBJECT NAME: Programming Technique
SUBJECT CREDIT: 3

SUBJECT CODE 2.: DCS1062
SUBJECT NAME: Current Issues in ICT
SUBJECT CREDIT: 3

SUBJECT CODE 3.: DCS1083
SUBJECT NAME: Object Oriented Programming
SUBJECT CREDIT: 3
Subject Name                  Subject Code          Credit
------------------------------------------------------------------
Programming Technique
  DCS1053               3
Current Issues in ICT
  DCS1062               3
Object Oriented Programming
  DCS1083               3
Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 53.708 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
Subject Name                Subject Code           Credit    
---------------------------------------------------------------  
Programming Technique       DCS1053                   3  
Current Issues in ICT       DCS1062                   3
Object Oriented Programming DCS1083                   3
```

Comment: How would you like the output to look? What are your expectatins concerning the effect of `'\t'` ?

Comment: `subjName[totalSubj][20]` does not match `fgets(subjName[i],50,stdin);`. Why do you tell `fgets` to write `50` `char`s into a buffer of `20`?

Comment: `"Programming Technique"` has 22 characters. How much space do you think is available where you are trying to store it?

Comment: see you are using big name as subject name so make sure you are giving proper space. use multiple times `\t` and run and trial. and see what works perfect for you

Comment: Explaining that in a comment did not really work huh? Why not [edit] the question and give those details there, instead of mangling and hiding them down here in the comments?

Comment: @mch Thank you for informing, however the output is still the same although I've corrected it to 50

Comment: @Yunnosch I've updated the post, thank you.

Comment: I recommend to now [edit] again and explain in detail your understanding of the memory areas you use in your code. What size are they? Where are they used? What size do they need to be for what you are doing with them? Feel free to state where you are just guessing. Refer to the comments above in comments by your own to give feedback.  Ask specifically which lines those comments refer to if necessary.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&subjCode[i]);` ==> `scanf("%s",subjCode[i]);`. Also `fgets` writes also the newline into the buffer, you do not remove that.

Comment: @AnkitMishra Thanks, I hope to have them in the same line, however the 'subject name' and 'subject code' are still on different lines although I didn't add \n or \t between them.

Comment: it is obvious if they don't fit into screen they will use second line.

Comment: Please modify your code to make output markers which allow to find out where the unwanted whitespace/newlines are coming from. E.g. `printf("\n<%s>  ",nameSub[i]);printf("(%s)\t\t",codeSub[i]);printf("[%d]",credSub[i]);` and show the output of that.

Comment: Are you aware of this detail in https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets "Parsing stops if a newline character is found, in which case **str will contain that newline character**..."?

Answer (score 1):

you read the subject name using `fgets` so that one contains the newline and you print it => the subject is alone on its line, then on the next line you have the code and the credit

to read a string containing spaces except newline you can use `scanf` :

```
scanf(" %49[^\n]", &subjName[i]);
```

the space at beginning of the format allows to remove spaces/newline/.. before the first non space character, that allows to bypass the newline enter after the code

to have your output as you expect you cannot write a fixed amount of space/tab, use the capacities of `printf` to write on a given width

also it is not consistent to have a width to print smaller than the size of the fields you can read

Comment: @Yunnosch no because the characters inside [] are not read

Comment: @Yunnosch the newline is bypassed reading the credit whose is a number

Comment: Yes that is the explanation. Consider explaining it more explicitly, more pointedly in the answer. Just to make it obvious to the inexerienced (and the nitpickers like me... ;-) ).

Answer (score 1):

The function `fgets()` takes the newline as an input and it inserts the newline char into the variable and you get disastrous output.

This code may help you to solve your problem (handy explains are added in comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// defining macros the maximum lengths of array as a constant    
#define SUB_NAME_MAX 50
#define SUB_CODE_MAX 10

// function signature
void formed_output(int, char [][SUB_NAME_MAX], char [][SUB_CODE_MAX], int[]);

int main(void) {
    int total;

    printf("How many subjects to be registered? ");
    scanf("%d", &total);

    char sub_code[total][SUB_CODE_MAX], sub_name[total][SUB_NAME_MAX];
    int sub_credit[total];

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        printf("\nSUBJECT CODE %d.: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s", &sub_code[i]);

        printf("SUBJECT NAME: ");
        fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END); // to avoid skipping user input
        fgets(sub_name[i], SUB_NAME_MAX, stdin);

        char *pos;
        if ((pos=strchr(sub_name[i], '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0'; // this one is the trick which will help to
                         // remove newline of each 'sub_name' array

        printf("SUBJECT CREDIT: ");
        scanf("%d", &sub_credit[i]);
    }

    printf("\n"); // for good-looking purpose

    formed_output(total, sub_name, sub_code, sub_credit);

    return 0;
}

void formed_output(int total, char name[][SUB_NAME_MAX], char code[][SUB_CODE_MAX], int cred[]) {
    printf("Subject Name                       Subject Code          Credit\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        printf("%-35s", name[i]); // left-justified for next 35 places
        printf("%-22s", code[i]); // left-justified for next 22 places
        printf("%d \n", cred[i]);
    }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
How many subjects to be registered? 3 

SUBJECT CODE 1.: DCS1053
SUBJECT NAME: Programming Technique    
SUBJECT CREDIT: 3

SUBJECT CODE 2.: DCS1062
SUBJECT NAME: Current Issues in ICT
SUBJECT CREDIT: 3

SUBJECT CODE 3.: DCS1083
SUBJECT NAME: Object Oriented Programming
SUBJECT CREDIT: 3
Subject Name                       Subject Code          Credit
---------------------------------------------------------------
Programming Technique              DCS1053               3
Current Issues in ICT              DCS1062               3
Object Oriented Programming        DCS1083               3
```

Comment: as I say on my answer you can simplify your life doing `scanf(" %49[^\n]", &subjName[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

> everything gone misaligned in the table of my output.

`fgets()` retains a `'\n'` it may have read.
`fgets()` and `scanf()` do not play well together.

---

Avoid using both `fgets()` with `scanf()`.  The first reads a *line*, the 2nd does not.

With *line* inputs, use `fgets()`.  Use width limitations when filling a character array.

Using `fgets()` with `sscanf()` is OK.

```
void userInput() {
  char buf[100];
  int totalSubj;

  printf("\nHow many subject to be registered: ");
  fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); 
  sscanf(buf, "%d", &total);

  char subjCode[totalSubj][10], subjName[totalSubj][50];
  int subjCred[totalSubj];

  for (int i=0; i<totalSubj; i++) {
    printf("\nSUBJECT CODE %d.: ",i+1);
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); 
    sscanf(buf, "%9s", subjCode[i]);  // & not used when calling with an array

    printf("SUBJECT NAME: ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); 
    sscanf(buf, "%49s", subjName[i]);

    printf("SUBJECT CREDIT: ");
    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin); 
    sscanf(buf, "%d",&subjCred[i]);
  }

  formOutput(totalSubj, subjName, subjCode, subjCred);
}
```

Better code would also test the return values of `fgets()` and `sscanf()` to look for errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in `formOutput()`

```
 printf("Subject Name \t\t\tSubject Code\t\tCredit\n");
printf("-------------\t\t\t------------\t\t------\n");
int i=0;
for( i=0;i<subjTotal;i++)
{
    printf("\n%s\t\t\t",nameSub[i]);
    printf("%s\t\t",codeSub[i]);
    printf("%d\n",credSub[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why? What is the difference? How is this supposed to help?

Comment: listen you are taking subject name which has space so please use `scanf(" %[^\n]s", &subjName[i]);` while scanning. and formating part is something which you have to check by trial

Comment: You quote the solution to the main problem form the other answer - in a comment. Your answer itself does not provide a solution. Guessing the size of inputs and hoping on some tabulators to fix the alignment is an .. optimistic ... approach at best.

Comment: The trailing `s` in `scanf(" %[^\n]s", ` serves no purpose.  Better to drop it.